# What word processing software was used by the Apple //e outside of Australia?

Tags: apple-ii

I did enjoy the software that schools provided with the Apple //e in the late 1980's. My memory of word processing software was:

1. [Zardax](https://collections.museumvictoria.com.au/items/1223763)
2. Multiscribe

I was in the Australian school system. So other countries may have used different software for writing and word processing. So have I missed any other word processing software for the Apple //e? I don't recall using Wordstar.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Apple_II_word_processors lists a few notables, but there are many more (Magic Window, Screenwriter ][, ...) Were you looking for something specific, or just a list of titles?

Comment: So far this sounds like a list question which would make it OT - and me inclined to vote for closing. As fadden already said (while providing  a nice list-link - there where quite a lot), stating a more to the point reasoning, what you are looking for, could save the question - and bring the knowledge you want.

Comment: I was really trying to find software that i never saw or used.

Comment: Well, there where dozends, if not hundrets. It was an open playfield without todays one size fits all products. Just, as by RC.SE terms, questions asking for lists of something are by default Off-Topic.

Comment: Wasn't AppleWorks the de-facto gold standard in Aplle //e word processing?  Did anything else even come close?  I had to suffer through using SpeedScript and/or Bank Street Writer on my C-64... (SpeedScript was actually quite good), but nothing could touch AppleWorks.

Comment: AppleWorks didn't come out until around 1985, IIRC, which would be 2 years after the introduction of the //e. Before then, there were certainly versions of Bank Street Writer that were updated for the //e and as well an update for the popular Apple Writer did come out in 1983 to support the new machine. You could say that AppleWorks became the gold standard eventually because it was that much better, but it certainly didn't appear for a few years.

Comment: List questions are usually shut down on this site, unfortunately. Anyway, you could have a look in the word processing software directory at the ["Asimov" archive](ftp://ftp.apple.asimov.net/pub/apple_II/images/productivity/word_processing/). I notice they don't have the excellent FullText Pro 80 software we used in NZ. It featured WYSIWYG, double hires monochrome graphics, spell checking, mail-merge etc. Photos of the box and feature list are [here](https://classic-computers.org.nz/forums/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=1501&start=15).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it clearly asks for a list answer (or worse a link only to some list) - and the first answer already promised to compile one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am making [a list](http://hoop-la.ca/apple2/edit/) which will include not just word processors, but also editors and related tools.  I am fairly sure many of these were, and still are, used in Australia.  This is my first reading about Zardax -- thanks for [the link](https://collections.museumvictoria.com.au/items/1223763).  Wordstar ran on CP/M which was popular at the time.

Comment: It's likely this question will be closed, unfortunately, but have a look at my comment on the question. I think the author of Fulltext Pro 80 resisted efforts to export it, but it might have been used in Australia. I remember using Wordstar in NZ too.

Comment: There was also some weird software called Diskmuncher that the teacher handed out so that people could make an "illegal" copy of software for themselves! We were 80's kids: we were illegal!